# Axios delete req.params undefined react nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

In my index.js file

```
app.delete("/delete/:nurseid", (req, res) => {
    const nurseID = req.params.nurseID
    console.log(nurseID); // undefined
    connection.query('DELETE FROM nurse WHERE nurseID = ?', nurseID , (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            res.send(result);
        }
    });
});
```

React app.js

```
      const deleteNurse = (nurseID) => {
        console.log(nurseID);

        Axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/delete/${nurseID}`, { 
          data: { nurseID: nurseID}
        });
      }
```

After sending this request, the backend returns that req.params.nurseID is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the name of nurseId:

```
const nurseid = req.params.nurseid
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `nurseid` not `nurseID`. You may have noticed it by now.

```
const nurseID = req.params.nurseid
```